# I'm trying to get a modal to open after hitting the menu button

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I'm trying to get my modal to open after hitting the menu button.

here is my code

```
 HTML

<div class="modal fade modal-gallery" id="menu_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

                <div class="nav-modal">
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="b-nav">
                            <li><a class="scroll" href="#home">HOME</a></li>
                            <li><a class="scroll" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>


                            <li><a class="scroll" href="#memeorial>MeMEORIAL</a></li>
                            <li><a class="scroll" href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
            </div>

        </div>
        </div>
```

now targetting the modal created

```
 <div class="slide-content" >
  <a href="#menu_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="menu_modal" 
   class="scroll hvr-bounce-to-bottom"><div class="cus_menu_parent" 
   title="Menu">
   <div class="cus_menu"></div>
   <div class="cus_menu"></div>
   <div class="cus_menu"></div>
   </div> </a>
   </div>
```

now here is my css. I have not done much on the styling because I am trying to get the modal to work and later make much of a fancy style

```
<style type="text/css">
 .modal{
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69);
background-size: cover;
padding: 0 !important;

}

.modal-dialog {
width: 60%; 
margin:4em auto;
```

}

I know I am missing something but I can't seem to find it please help me out

Comment: Did you add bootstrap's javascript files?

Comment: Where is the JS? please go to https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp    .If you use Bootstrap

Comment: @AllanJebaraj yes i did add bootstrap js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify `data-target="#menu_modal"` instead of `data-target="menu_modal"`

You did not add the hash tag.

It'll work good.

More details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

Comment: oh yeah,  the "#" was missing, added the tag lol. it works sweet, I thought I had it in all the time
 xd thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#menu_modal" class="scroll hvr-bounce-to-bottom">
```

Value of `data-target` should be id of the modal(`#menu_modal`)

Also when targeting modal using `a` tag, add `href="#"` instead of id of modal

**I added "Click Here" just for the sake of example**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="modal fade modal-gallery" id="menu_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

    <div class="nav-modal">
      <nav>
        <ul class="b-nav">
          <li><a class="scroll" href="#home">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a class="scroll" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a class="scroll" href="#memeorial">MeMEORIAL</a></li>
          <li><a class=" scroll " href="#contact ">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slide-content ">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#menu_modal" class="scroll hvr-bounce-to-bottom">Click here
    <div class="cus_menu_parent " title="Menu ">
      <div class="cus_menu "></div>
      <div class="cus_menu "></div>
      <div class="cus_menu "></div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```